# Differences in assigning values to assembly registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm learning assembly in nasm syntax for x86 architecture. I've found
several examples of HelloWorld program and also downloaded some other
examples such as Caculator. - I'm confused of some thing i've found,
such as, what the difference between two samples mentioned below:

```
  mov eax, 4 ; sys_write
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, string ; string in .data section
  mov edx, str_len ; string length
  int 80h
```

Now see another example (focus on registers):

```
  mov eax, str_len
  mov ebx, string
  mov ecx, 4
  mov edx, 1
  int 80h
```

You can see in the above two examples, focus on regesters. Whats the
difference if I assign "eax, 4" or "edx, 4" or what if I assign 
"ecx, 4". Whats the difference?

Are registers "specific" for particular type of value or I can assign
any value to any register?

Note: I'm learning NASM, if you found this question silly, please dont
bite. I cant even understand this difference in Assembly.

Note: My target platform is 32 bit Linux.

Comment: the "other example" is simply wrong

Comment: `int 80h` is 32 bit linux system service call. Is that your target platform? With asm questions always add your target platform, as for example 64 bit linux has different way of outputting text to console, so has the windows OS or old DOS... the "nasm" assembler covers all of these common target platforms, so it's not clear which one you are trying to use/learn about.

Comment: @Ped7g i've added it. Thanks for informing :-)

Comment: Every register is separate and uniquely named. If a routine expects a particular value in a particular register, you can't just put that value in a different register since the routine would not find it there. It's kind of like if you have two kids, Billy and Sue. If you call Sue, would you expect Billy to respond, or vice versa? If you feed Billy, is Sue no longer hungry?

Comment: @lurker: Sue is always hungry and no matter how much she eats, she doesn't put on weight. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis that sounds to me like `$zero` register of MIPS ... :) whatever you write into it, it still reads as zero... <g>

Comment: @Tommylee2k that's super helpful to a beginner, "you're wrong, but I'm not gonna tell you why!!"

Answer (score 3):

> Are registers "specific" for particular type of value or I can assign any value to any register?

On x86 the CPU registers are mostly "general purpose", i.e. in your own code you can use `eax` vs `edx` quite freely, except few instructions which are using implicit registers (`div, mul, stos, movs, ...`).

Then there are special registers (segment, control, flag, `eip`).

So you can usually assign any value to any [general] register.

> Whats the difference if I assign "eax, 4" or "edx, 4" or what if I assign "ecx, 4".

The difference is, that value `4` will be stored either `eax` or in `edx` register. Both of them are 32 bit "general purpose" x86 registers, both are storing only thirty-two 0 or 1 values, nothing more (also they don't store any information about "type" or how the value did originate in the register, how it was formatted in source, etc... `mov eax,16` is identical to `mov eax,0x10`, the CPU does see only the final binary machine code, which is identical for both variants of source and will load binary value `00..0010000` (16) into the register `eax`). I.e. so far not much of difference, except your personal preference.

The part, where the choice of `eax` vs `edx` will start to matter is upon using those registers (interpreting the bit values in certain way), and that in your example happens with `int 80h`.

That instruction is calling in 32 bit linux kernel services, i.e. there's thousands of code lines hidden behind that, doing various things for applications, and those lines were already compiled by the distribution vendor (or yourself), and they are part of kernel binary.

And the linux developers already decided, that the `eax` contains id-number of service requested, and other registers contain arguments for that particular service.

`eax = 4` is `sys_write`, while your second example with `eax = str_len` will call some other service, depending on the length of string (`"Hello world."` is 12 characters long, so the linux kernel will try to serve the `sys_chdir` service for `eax = 12` argument).

So your second example doesn't output "Hello world", and judging by the context it's just invalid example.

When you are calling some external code not belonging to you, you have to search the documentation what is the proper way to call it, and where/how arguments are passed and what conditions must be fulfilled (for example in 64 bit mode you must usually also align the stack `rsp` address to 16B boundaries, when calling C functions).

For 32 bit linux kernel the system service docs ... not sure which docs are best and reliable, this link from x86 tag info looks to have detailed and full information about how to do such service calls: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/

While this link from google https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ lists particular services and expected arguments (combining that with checking the linux manual for `sys_write` and others should be enough).

The particular `sys_write` from your example expects arguments as:

- eax = 4
- ebx = file descriptor (1 = stdout)
- ecx = data to write (memory address of first byte of data)
- edx = length of data to write (in bytes).

Comment: Worth mentioning that the 32-bit system-call numbers are in `asm/unistd_32.h`.